# React Native: Activity and metrics tracking libraries?

Tags: react-native

I'm looking into adding a tracking library (something like what Google Analytics does for the web) to my React Native app.

Are there tools out there to track user activity like swiping, tapping on stuff, etc? I did a quick search but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To track events you can use google analytics in react-native either as a javascript or a native implementation.

The key difference is that in the native implementation you get a some metadata handled automatically. ( such as device UUID, device model, viewport size, OS version ).

Javascript implementation: https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga

Native bridge: https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge

Comment: decided to go with firebase since google seems to be pushing for it